# Enforcing minimum passphrase length with gpg

Tags: gpg

When encrypting a file with `--symmetric` option, `gpg` asks for the passphrase using the `pinentry` program (small window). I want it to reject passphrases below a certain length.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be configured with `gpg`. You need the `gpg-agent` configuration to do that. Have a look at its man page and see the options `--min-passphrase-len` and `--enforce-passphrase-constraints`.

As you probably not want to have all passphrase operations be affected by them you may use a separate configuration:

```
mkdir ~/.gnupg-symmetric
$EDITOR ~/.gnupg-symmetric/gpg-agent.conf # add those options
GPG_AGENT_INFO= gpg --homedir ~/.gnupg-symmetric --symmetric file
```